# How to keep focus on a selected button

Tags: javascript, html, css

there are two buttons on the page, when you click on one, it changes color.

How to make this focus not disappear after clicking on the empty field next to it?

```
<button id="button1">Text 1</button>
<button id="button2">Text 2</button>

.button1 {
height: 48px;
width: 240px;}

.button1:hover {
background-color: red;}

.button1:focus {
background-color: green;}

.button2 {
height: 48px;
width: 240px;}

.button2:hover {
background-color: red;}

.button2:focus {
background-color: green;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so with Javascript.
Note that you are also adding `ids` to your buttons but in your styles you are targeting `classes`.

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btns.forEach((btn)=> {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(document.querySelector('button.active')){
         document.querySelector('button.active').classList.remove('active');
        }
        btn.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

```css
#button1 {
height: 48px;
width: 240px;}

#button1:hover {
background-color: red;}

#button1:focus, #button1.active {
background-color: green;}

#button2 {
height: 48px;
width: 240px;}

#button2:hover {
background-color: red;}

#button2:focus, #button2.active {
background-color: green;}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Text 1</button>
<button id="button2">Text 2</button>
```

Comment: buttons change color permanently and only the one that was clicked should change. The point is that one should always be focused even after clicking on the empty field next to it

Comment: So each time a new button gets clicked the other button gets restored?

Comment: "So each time a new button gets clicked the other button gets restored?" Yes

Comment: There is no need for javascript, but it really depends on everyone's wish to implement it. I added an answer where you can implement it without any javascript, but only HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with HTML and CSS only by styling the labels of radio inputs as the following suggestion.

The advantage of this implementation is that you don't have to maintain another element (by javascript) if you need the button value to be submitted through a form.

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

span > input[type=radio] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

span > label {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span > label:hover {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

span > input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <input name="my-button" value="1" type="radio" id="my-button-1" />
    <label for="my-button-1">Text 1</label>
</span>
<span>
    <input name="my-button" value="2" type="radio" id="my-button-2" />
    <label for="my-button-2">Text 2</label>
</span>
```

Comment: This is a clean approach indeed. Agreed!